# How to add count method on Bookshelf.js model?

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I've got the following tables:

- `books`
- `book_reviews`
- `users`

Here are the models that correspond to said tables:

```
const BookReview = require('./BookReview').model;
const User = require('./User').model;

module.exports.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'books',

  user: function() {
    return this.hasOne(User, 'user_id');
  },

  reviews: function() {
    return this.hasMany(BookReview);
  }
});

module.exports.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'book_reviews',

  user: function() {
    // Prevent circular dependency.
    const User = require('./User').model;
    return this.belongsTo(User, 'user_id');
  },
});

module.exports.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',

  reviews: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(BookReview, 'user_id');
  }
});
```

I'm looking up a Book and trying to fetch all reviews that it has (and all users who wrote those reviews are attached to the reviews that come back), which it currently is doing with the following statement:

```
return Book.forge({
    id: req.params.id,
    type: req.params.type
  }).fetch({withRelated: ['reviews', 'reviews.user'], require: true}).then(function(book) {
    console.log(book.toJSON());
    return book;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  });
```

};

And the output from `book.toJSON()` from above looks like:

Output from book.toJSON() from above:

```
{ id: 1,
  type: 'novel',
  slug: 'catcher-in-the-rye',
  user_id: 1,
  name: 'Catcher in the Rye',
  created_at: Tue Oct 04 2016 22:35:42 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  updated_at: Tue Oct 04 2016 22:35:42 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  reviews: 
   [ { id: 14,
       user_id: 2,
       book_id: 1,
       rating: 3,
       review: 'Test',
       created_at: Wed Oct 05 2016 20:47:34 GMT-0700 (PDT),
       updated_at: Wed Oct 05 2016 20:47:34 GMT-0700 (PDT),
       user: [Object] } ] }
```

I want to add a method to every user that is returned within the reviews from the output above that has a count of all of their total reviews.

I tried to add something like this to the `User` model, but I couldn't quite do it properly.

```
numReviews: function(userId) {
        return new BookReview.query(function(qb){
            qb.where("user_id",userId);
            qb.count();
        }).fetch();
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add the method to every instance of the `User` model, then you could overwrite the `constructor` function like follows

```
var User=bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  constructor:function(){
    bookshelf.Model.apply(this, arguments);

    this.numReviews=function(){
      var thisUser=this;
      return new BookReview.query(function(qb){
        qb.where("user_id",thisUser.attributes.userId);
        qb.count();
        }).fetch();
    }
  }
});
```

But I believe that these approach would perform poorly, so maybe you should try another option. Unfortunately I haven't used the bookshelf library that much, so I don't really have any advice on a more performant way to do the task.

Anyway, hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

After your line `console.log(book.toJSON());`
you can access the count of reviews for book by using the length parameter.

```
console.log(book.reviews.length);
```

Because is is an `array` of book reviews, denoted in the `JSON` as `[...]`

Comment: I want the total count of the number of books each user has for every book. This would just give me the count of the books in the collection.

Comment: @bob_cobb, I don't understand "count of the number of books each user has for every book"